# Lost infotips inside Microsoft Word 2007 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word-2007

Normally, inside Word, I get a tooltip when hovering over change tracked text to show the author and date and time or change, however, something changed on my computer and I am not sure what because now the tooltip only shows for a fleeting moment, starting to draw the box outline before being dismissed.

Any ideas how to resolve this or what might be causing the immediate dismissal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Office Setup, choose Repair and then reboot the system.